# represent in "front of, before or in dealing with"

Tags: word-usage

Which one may more officially works?
To represent company "in front of" community, "before" community, or "dealing with" community.

Answer (score 0):

One can represent a company "for" a community if one is describing the scope of one's representation - e.g. for specific regions or specific accounts. This would sound pompous if said to the community.

As a representative, once can "work with" or "deal with" specific clients, regions, cities, etc. Maybe "in matters relating to [company]". This would sound better when introducing myself to the community

"before" sounds pretentious, like a courtroom

"in front of" sounds odd. I cannot figure out a place where I would use that

Answer (score 0):

"in front of" and "before" are nearly identical in context.  Both are correct and idiomatic; but, before is preferred as better English speakers avoid the extra words when they don't provide extra clarity or emotional impact.

"dealing with" is an entirely different kind of relationship.  You may deal with something that is behind you, for example your past.  You may deal with something that has no specific location (as in dealing with your taxes).  It implies some sort of relationship where effort is involved, sometimes implying endurance of a unfavorable relationship.

In all of your examples, the most idiomatic way of expressing this isn't listed.

> I'd like to represent the company for the community.

Which implies that you're servicing the community.  Equally idiomatic is

> I'd like to represent the company to the community.

Which implies that you're presenting something to the community.

The latter one keeps the identity of yourself closer to the company, the first one is vague about your identity, you might actually be a member of the community you're interacting with, and not a member of the company.